# Ruby on Rails has_many and polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, has-many

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to understand abstract class. Maybe I still have in mind Java structure...

I followed many tutorials and there is still things I'd need to understand. Let's say we want to build a contact book. In this address book, we have people and companies.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end
```

Everything's working fine for now. Now, we have different users, each one has an address book.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :addressbook
end

class Addressbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many ??????
end
```

How do i list all the addresses no matter if they are a person or a company? Because i'd like to display them in alphabetical order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem :

Your `Person` and `Company` must `belongs_to` Addressbook.
An `Addressbook` `has_many` `:persons` and `has_many` `:companies`.
An `Addressbook` `has_many` `:person_addresses` and `has_many` `:company_addresses` (using `:through`)

After, you can define a function `addresses`, which is the union of `person_addresses` and `company_addresses`.

An other solution is to declare a super-class for `Person` and `Company`, named `Addressable` for example. I think it's a prettier way.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable
end

class Addressable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  belongs_to :addressbooks
end

class Person < Addressable
end

class Company < Addressable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :addressbook
end

class Addressbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addressables
  has_many :addresses, :through => :addressables
end
```

Comment: Yes, a super-class seems the best, do you have any hints how i should do it? I'll google it, but i'm not very comfortable diving in those concepts since i'm very new to Rails.

Comment: This works just fine! One last question: is it possible for Person or company to have attributes that the other doesn't have? For example, can a person have an age (not the company) and the company have a founder?

Comment: Just answered my own question, edited your post. It works! :D

Comment: @SophieDéziel Of course you can ! But don't forget to add this specific columns into `Adressable` classes. This columns will be automatically `NULL` in the others types.